# Plot Plane to Intersect 3D Contour Plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, modeling

I have a 3D model of a heart in Mathematica and I'm trying to create a plane so that the open surface (as seen in the image below) is cut off so that the heart can have a solid, level surface.  How can I combine this plane with my 3D contour plot?

```
heart = (2 x^3 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 - (1/10) x^2 z^3 - y^2 z^3
planey = z
g = {Normal[      
   ContourPlot3D[{heart == 0}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 
     1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, Mesh -> None, 
    ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Red]]   ], planey}
 gn = Normal[
  g /. GeometricTransformation[prims_, 
     tf_List] :> (GeometricTransformation[prims, #] & /@ tf)]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 reg = (2 x^3 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 - (1/10) x^2 z^3 - y^2 z^3 <= 0 && 
   x >= 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Implicit regions could be refined but is not as pleasing "out of the box", e.g.

```
DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y, z}], Table[{-2, 2}, {3}]],
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Will this help you?

```
c1 = ContourPlot3D[{heart == 0}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Red], 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x > -0.3]];
c2 = ContourPlot3D[x == -.3, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, 
  Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Blue], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, heart < 0]];
Show[c1, c2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's helpful, but I still need the open surface that lets the heart become a bowl to be intersected by a plane or solidify the entire heart.

Comment: Well, just do it the other way around to close the heart: Use the heart expression of `RegionFunction` and draw a *parametric plane*. Please look at the other styling options like `BoundaryStyle` too.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the boundary `Line` with a `Polygon`:

```
heart = (2 x^3 + y^2 + z^2 - 1)^3 - (1/10) x^2 z^3 - y^2 z^3;
g = Show[
  ContourPlot3D[heart == 0,
    {x, 0., 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5},
    Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Red],
     AxesLabel -> Automatic] /. 
   Line[p_] :> {Opacity[0.8, Red], EdgeForm[], 
     Polygon[p, VertexNormals -> ConstantArray[{-1, 0, 0}, Length[p]]]},
  PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`RegionPlot3D` works too:

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[heart <= 0,
  {x, 0., 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5},
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8, Red], 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic],
 PlotRange -> 1.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`BoundaryStyle` may be used to remove or change the edge.

Happy Valentine's Day!